# Make that answer a canonical answer to "how to quit gracefully in a professional way"

Tags: discussion

I am not exactly sure, if this should be really done by going meta but I want to attract your attention to a question that has been asked many times in pretty much all possible way : [Should I wait to leave my company after I finish a big project? What's the best way to do this?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/166046/should-i-wait-to-leave-my-company-after-i-finish-a-big-project-whats-the-best)

The answer provided is the most excellent and complete answer on the matter I have seen as it emcompass the process to follow and also how you should behave professionally and also on your own interest (like not burning bridges). I think we should make it a canonical answer and add it to the relevant tag (job-change, resignation ?).

And for those that say "what is the best way to do this" is attracting opinions. Just read as "what is the professional way to do this".

Comment: Sounds like this is an answer to "How should I gracefully resign / move on?"? We have a similar question [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7149) but that's specifically when you're very new. Sounds like there's an opportunity to create a canonical question. If you want a canonical answer it needs a canonical question. You could use this post here to create that question with some consensus input and in a way that will avoid it attracting close flags, then post it.

Comment: The answer author can then either repost his answer or we could close the linked question as a duplicate and transfer the answer to the new post as part of that (post merge, reserved for moderators). This will keep its reputation but the timing might be important, especially if the new post hits HNQ, and we'd want to avoid discouraging new answers to a canonical question.

Comment: Oh just noticed this... Appreciate the vote of confidence. As the author of the answer in question, happy to move/repost it or have it moved wherever.  I was surprised myself that of all the questions about resigning there wasn't a straightforward one, I looked briefly.   Do note my answer only addresses permanent employment (contracts ending is different), leaving one job for another (and not randomly quitting) and is mostly relevant to white collar type jobs (lower end shift type work would merit different advice).

Comment: @mxyzplk-SEstopbeingevil question posted : https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/166625/how-do-i-resign-gracefully-professionally

Comment: copied answer over, thanks @Walfrat

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is potentially the canonical question already: [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-can-one-resign-from-a-new-job-gracefully)

Although this question asks about a new job specifically, the accepted answer really describes a good process for approaching any resignation.

It has many votes and multiple references as a duplicate.

Comment: Nice one. I was sure we already had past Q&As regarding this topic.

Comment: @DarkCygnus what about moving the two main answer I have to that one and close mine then ?

Comment: @Walfrat I'd say that you leave your answers where they are. Not much of a point moving around answers, if they already served their purpose (you already helped the user that posted and you answered to). However, in the future we now know there is a canonical-ish post of this matter, and we should vote as dupe or redirect to that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to suggestion I will try to phrase a concise canonical question for it.

> I am currently working at my company and I would like to leave for another opportunity.
>
> I want to search for another job but I would like to quit this one in a professional way meaning:
>
> - in the best of my interest
> - not burning bridges with coworkers/manager/company
> - not being dragged down by my soon-to-be ex company.
>
> What would be the steps to leave from a company job?

Comment: Generally speaking when posting canonical question I'd advise being clear and avoiding a hypothetical "I am doing X and want to do Y". Instead you can just keep it to the "How do I resign gracefully/professionally?" in the title and then ask "What are the steps involved when resigning a job, and how do I leave on good terms / while remaining professional".

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest this as an alternative canonical question:

> I have a white collar, permanent job I would like to leave. I would like to quit this one in a professional way, meaning without burning bridges while also preserving my own interests as much as possible.
>
> What are the suggested steps to leave such a job? Are there common mistakes I should avoid?

Comment: seems like you have more vote. Maybe wait 3 more days so it have been open a full week and go for it :)

Comment: "Find another job first" is commonly given advice when someone says they want to quit, as it's not always clear whether they intend to do or have done that. So I think that would be better as part of the answer than given in the question. There isn't really much to *say* in terms of that, so it wouldn't lengthen an answer much, but it can be important to say it nonetheless.

Comment: You can't leave a blue collar job in a professional manner?

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter of course you can, but the  person who wrote the answer that this canonical question is for said their answer is specifically for white collar jobs.

Comment: @Kat if we are singling out this for white collar jobs only, then perhaps it's not as canonical as we think... I suggest we consider if this can be extrapolated to white or blue collar jobs, so it is in fact canonical.

Comment: That’s not a good definition of canonical.  Ending contracts deserves a good comprehensive answer, ending low end retail/food service jobs are very different..  getting involuntary terminated is different...  we don’t need to combine all that up that’s called “a book.”